# Windows 8 simulator keeps loading forever

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, windows-store-apps, simulator

I'm working on Visual Studio 2012 running on Windows 8 (32 bit), developing Windows Store app with C++
The app runs smooth on "local machine". But when I try to run it on the simulator, Build and Deploy succeeds but the simulator keeps loading forever! (dots coming from left and leaving at right)

When I close the simulator from the taskbar, VS gives me the following error: Unable to start the simulator. Cannot process request because the process (####) has exited.

I've been searching everywhere for a solution for a week now. The possible solutions I found were:
1. Changing the `fDenyChildConnections` registry.
2. Checking the "Automatically use my Windows logon name and password (and domain if any)" checkbox from the security tab of the network.
3. Updating graphics driver.
4. Disconnecting all networks.
5. Restarting VS/making new project.
6. Launching simulator from C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Windows Simulator\11.0\Microsoft.Windows.Simulator.exe
7. Updating VS.

The problem is still there. Does anybody have a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I performed a clean install of Windows 8.1 x64 and the simulator is running smoothly. I guess running 32 bit windows on a 64 bit architecture was the cause of this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try to see if "Remote Desktop Services" is enabled, if no enable it as manual and start it.

Answer (score 0):

​I had the same issue and the reason was lack of Hyper-V. I installed Hyper-V and the simulator worked.